# How to get the OS user name of the oracle software installation owner on unix platform?

Tags: oracle

How to get the OS user name of the oracle software installation owner on unix platform?

Most of the time, Oracle Home directory owner is the one, or the name is 'grid' or 'oracle'; but is there any sure-shot way to know the Oracle Software Owner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every separate *Oracle home* could have its different owner (*grid* for the *GI* home, *oracle* for the *RDBMS* home, for example). The owner/group of a particular *Oracle* home is easily accessible 
using the *ls* *Unix* command:

```
ls -ld "$ORACLE_HOME"
```

Just read the *Oracle* official documentation (the quick installation guide should be sufficient): some commands need to be run as the *ORACLE_HOME* owner, other as *root*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically, or just in general?

For Oracle homes that are started by the system, you could look in the startup scripts in the /etc/rc.d directory, which usually su to the oracle owner account to start the service. If I recall correctly, anyone in the dba group can technically be the "owner" and start the services, so the concept of Oracle "owner" is a bit loose.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file `/etc/oraInst.loc` which will always exist, even if you don't have `ORACLE_HOME` set. As DCookie [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606367/447514), the group is the important bit, that is `inst_group` in this file.